# Потеря пикселей при конвертации

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, android-studio, recyclerview

Суть задачи: Есть массив субтитров (long start, long end, string text). Мне нужно в зависимости от времени показа изменять ширину (int) для соответствующего item в RecyclerView. Если конец и начало следующего не совпадает по времени, то добавляю между ними пустой елемент

```
subs.add(new Subtitle(subtitles.get(i - 1).getEnd(), subtitles.get(i).getStart(), ""));
```

secInPx = 50; - количесвто пикселей на 1 секунду времени.
Сначала пробовал сделать так:

```
int width = (int) ((end - start)*secInPx)/1000
```

на каждом субтитре здесь удет потеря долей пикселей.за 45 минут видео (примерно 2000 субтитров) получаю смещение около 400 пикселей.

потом решил добавлять к следующему елементу все то что потеряли ранее.
rvWidth - ширина RecyclerView,

```
rvWidth = (videoDuration / 1000) * Constant.secInPx;

for (int i = 0; i < subtitles.size(); i++) {
     widthSums.add((int) ((subtitles.get(i).getEnd()*rvWidth)/videoDuration));
}

subtitles.get(0).setWidth(widthSums.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < subtitles.size(); i++) {
    subtitles.get(i).setWidth(widthSums.get(i) - widthSums.get(i-1));
}
```

сейчас получается смещение примерно в 30 пикселей, те же 45минут, 2000 субтитров.

[image: Скриншот]
Как можно еще более точно определать ширину елементов?

Красные линии то где должен начатся показ и конец субтитров "did the allfather"

Comment: Может использовать в расчётах `float` или `double`? Деление целых априори имеет погрешность, отбрасывая остаток.

Comment: я не могу потом использовать что-то кроме целого числа при изминении ширины. Во втором своем алгоритме я пробовал исправить погрешность, но пока так и не получил точного результата((

Comment: В момент применения можно привести к нужному типу. Я из вопроса не могу уловить суть проблемы - как связана ширина элемента с временем и 
их количеством?

Comment: уже пробовал так сделать, первый способ что я описал здесь. Редактировал вопрос, добавил фото. Субтитры теряют пиксели относительно шкалы времени